# How do I create a macro for a dialog box where I choose a directory path and it copies "Sheet1" to another sheet "A" in another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba, dialog

So basically I want to create a dialog box that pops up automatically when I open the workbook "Summary.xlsm".
Through this dialog box I want to be able to select a directory pathway for an excel file (*.xlsx,*.xls). 
Then once I submit the dialog box, I want the macro to automatically take "Sheet1" from the selected source and put it into the workbooks as Sheet "A". (I don't care whether this process involves the sheet being renamed to "A" before/after input or whether all the data from Sheet1 is copied into sheet "A" in the target workbook)

Ideally I would like to have a dialog box where I can type in a product type on the left (i.e. "A","B", etc...) and then choose the directory path on the left (i.e. "C:\Users....) with the option of adding additional rows if I get more product types.

**Here's a pic of how I'd like the dialog box to look like ideally:**
[image: Here's a pic of how I'd like the dialog box to look like ideally]

I just started teaching myself vbs and I'm on my 3rd day of ever using it so any help would be appreciated. Even bits and pieces of help such as how to create a dialog box to transfer sheets would be beneficial. 
What I described is my ideal but more basic system would be fine too. Thanks!!

Comment: What you want is a UserForm.  Check with Google for how to create one.  [This admittedly lengthy guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829070) describes how you can manipulate and use the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I see that you need to create a user from. This link should help in creating a user from http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/userform.html or even this one http://www.fontstuff.com/ebooks/free/fsuserforms.pdf.

Your second step is to to identify directory. So add a button in your user form and call this on the click event

```
Function GetFolder(strPath As String, strTitle As String) As String
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = strTitle
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With
NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

The parameters are the default location (strPath) and the title for the dialogbox 
(strTitle). This opens a folder picker to choose the required directory. 
[image: The dialog box looks as follows]

To run the code when you open the sheet you can take a look at this link http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/running-a-macro-when-excel-starts-HA001034628.aspx

Hope this can help you get started.

Comment: Thanks so so much! I ended up tweaking the code you gave me in order to create a "Browse.." command button on the Userform that actually input the directory file text in a textbox adjacent to it. BUt your help really got me on the right track yesterday and I ended up finishing and cleaning up my script today all thanks to you!